# Possible to build a 32bit adder from 32 1-bit adders?

Tags: module, addition, verilog

I am supposed to complete the module below,  by creating 32 assignment statements
doesn't seem to be the right way of doing this.  I know that i have to carry the cout up, 
but when create and test a yAdder using a client module, I get incorrect about like 1 + 1 =  4 billion.  lol.   I know what it should do, I just don't know how to do it in verilog.

```
    module yAdder(z,cout,a,b,cin);
output [31:0] z;
output cout;
input[31:0] a, b;
input cin;
wire[31:0] in,out;
yAdder1 mine[31:0](z,out,a,b,in);

assign in[0] = cin;
assign in[1] = out[0];
assign in[2] = out[0];
assign in[3] = out[0];
assign in[4] = out[0];
assign in[5] = out[0];
assign in[6] = out[0];
assign in[7] = out[0];
assign in[8] = out[0];
assign in[9] = out[0];
assign in[10] = out[0];
assign in[11] = out[0];
assign in[12] = out[0];
assign in[13] = out[0];
assign in[14] = out[0];
assign in[15] = out[0];
assign in[16] = out[0];
assign in[17] = out[0];
assign in[18] = out[0];
assign in[19] = out[0];
assign in[20] = out[0];
assign in[21] = out[0];
assign in[22] = out[0];
assign in[23] = out[0];
assign in[24] = out[0];
assign in[25] = out[0];
assign in[26] = out[0];
assign in[27] = out[0];
assign in[28] = out[0];
assign in[29] = out[0];
assign in[30] = out[0];
assign in[31] = out[0];
assign cout = out[0];


endmodule
```

and the 1 bit adder module.

```
module yAdder1(z,cout,a,b,cin);
output z, cout;
input a, b, cin;

xor left_xor(tmp,a,b);
xor right_xor(z,cin,tmp);
and left_and(outL,a,b);
and right_and(outR,tmp,cin);
or my_or(cout,outR,outL);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning `out[0]` to **all** `in` wires isn't probably the best idea. What you're looking for is probably something like this:

```
assign {cout,in} = {out,cin};
```

Comment: So this concates cout with out, and in with cin ?

Answer (score 0):

For this pre-lab, you're supposed imagine the 32-bit adder just like how we did our 4-bit adder in the last lab, and connect the carry-in/carry-out wires like this:

```
    assign in[0] = cin;
    assign in[1] = out[0];
    assign in[2] = out[1];
    assign in[3] = out[2];
    assign in[4] = out[3];
    assign in[5] = out[4];
    assign in[6] = out[5];
    assign in[7] = out[6];
    assign in[8] = out[7];
    assign in[9] = out[8];
    assign in[10] = out[9];
    assign in[11] = out[10];
    assign in[12] = out[11];
    assign in[13] = out[12];
    assign in[14] = out[13];
    assign in[15] = out[14];
    assign in[16] = out[15];
    assign in[17] = out[16];
    assign in[18] = out[17];
    assign in[19] = out[18];
    assign in[20] = out[19];
    assign in[21] = out[20];
    assign in[22] = out[21];
    assign in[23] = out[22];
    assign in[24] = out[23];
    assign in[25] = out[24];
    assign in[26] = out[25];
    assign in[27] = out[26];
    assign in[28] = out[27];
    assign in[29] = out[28];
    assign in[30] = out[29];
    assign in[31] = out[30];
    assign cout = out[31];
```